# Linux user mode network driver usage by application

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to understand more on the linux network drivers and user mode drivers. Have few questions. I searched online and have found few resources but are not clear enough

USer mode driver

How does the application interact with the driver to get data and send data? Is it through the general select, read, write?

Comment: Can be done in many ways -- IOCTLs, sysfs, interrupts, etc.